# How to apply xforms:repeat in two parallel columns

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I have n number of records in form data instance. i would like to iterate them and show it in 2 columns using xforms technology.

Consider i have following data instances:

```
<xforms:instance id="instanceData">
        <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <fruits>
                <fruit>
                    <fruit-name>Mango</fruit-name>
                </fruit>
                <fruit>
                    <fruit-name>Apple</fruit-name>
                </fruit>
                <fruit>
                    <fruit-name>Banana</fruit-name>
                </fruit>
                <fruit>
                    <fruit-name>Orange</fruit-name>
                </fruit>
                <fruit>
                    <fruit-name>Grape</fruit-name>
                </fruit>
                <fruit>
                    <fruit-name>Strawberry</fruit-name>
                </fruit>
            </fruits>
        </form>
    </xforms:instance>
```

i would like to show them in either of the following ways in the screen

`Mango`   `Apple`

`Banana`   `Orange`

`Grape`   `Strawberry`

AND

`Mango`   `Orange`

`Apple`   `Grape`

`Banana`   `Strawberry`

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
<xhtml:table>
    <xforms:repeat nodeset="fruits/fruit[position() mod 2 = 1]">
        <xhtml:tr>
            <xhtml:td><xforms:output value="fruit-name"/></xhtml:td>
            <xhtml:td><xforms:output value="following-sibling::fruit/fruit-name"/></xhtml:td>
        </xhtml:tr>
    </xforms:repeat>
</xhtml:table>
```

[Full source](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6900/resources/20110415-repeat-by-2.xhtml)